# Rows.Count returns the wrong number because?

Tags: excel, vba, count

im trying to use

```
Dim sh As Worksheet, lastEmptyRow As Long, rngEmptyU As Range
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastEmptyRow = sh.Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 Set rngEmptyU = sh.Range("U" & lastEmptyRow + 1)
    rngEmptyU.Select
```

Rows.count returns value too big, although i even dont have any formulas in the columns.
To double check, if i use the formula COUNTA in excel for example i have =IF(mdl!X1="","",mdl!X1)
In this column would be 300 names, but COUNTA returns 1200 as all the rows that have this formula.
Does anybody have some help for this, like change smth in the code?
I hope i made clear, please ask if not.

Comment: Have you tried `sh.Rows.Count`? The qualification is not implied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Cells With Formulas Evaluating To ""

In `Excel` for counting strings different than "", you can use something like this:

```
=COUNTA(X2:X1200)-COUNTBLANK(X2:X1200)
```

In `VBA` to go to the cell after the last cell containing a value different than "", but in another column, you can rather use the [`Find Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find):

```
Option Explicit

Sub getFirstEmptyCell()
    
    Const LastRowCol As Variant = "X"
    Const SourceCol As Variant = "U"
    
    Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = ActiveSheet
    Dim rng As Range
    ' Define last cell containing a value different then "", 
    ' even "" via formula (xlValues).
    Set rng = sh.Columns(LastRowCol).Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
    ' Check if any cell with value in column.
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    ' Applying Offset to first cell with no value (1), define cell.
    Set rng = rng.Offset(1, sh.Columns(SourceCol).Column - rng.Column)
    ' Select is usually avoided.
    rng.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Pure gold! Thank you so much for helping out : )